# GPG error; The following signatures were invalid KEYEXPIRED

Tags: apt

```
sudo apt-get update
```

get this error:

```
W: GPG error: http://debian.datastax.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1439480363 KEYEXPIRED 1439480363 KEYEXPIRED 1439480363
```

even after use --fix-missing, still have the same error.

Comment: @womble but it is not selected as right answer.

Comment: That isn't how this site works.  We don't duplicate questions just so a different answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually the problem come from [What should I do when I got the KEYEXPIRED error message after an apt-get update?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7145/what-should-i-do-when-i-got-the-keyexpired-error-message-after-an-apt-get-update/718435#718435)

I can not select the kynana's answer as the best answer so I just put it here. Thank you @Kynan https://serverfault.com/users/53358/kynan

To find any expired repository keys and their IDs, use apt-key as follows:

```
sudo apt-key list | grep expired
```

You will get a result similar to the following:

```
pub   4096R/BE1DB1F1 2011-03-29 [expired: 2014-03-28]
```

The key ID is the bit after the / i.e. BE1DB1F1 in this case.

To update the key, run

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net BE1DB1F1
```